# How to make class having generic parameter visible in inspector in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have a below code and I want to make it visible in in unity, which is not happening currently. I have added `SerializeField` as well

```
[SerializeField]
public class PropertyTypeAndSprite<T> 
{
    public T propertyType;
    public Sprite sprite;
}
[SerializeField]
public enum A
{
    C,
    D
}
public List<PropertyTypeAndSprite<A>> aTypeAndSprites;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That should be `[System.Serialiable]`, not `[SerializeField]`. But it still won't be enough.

Comment: And templated classes never work in the inspector, except List<T>, which is a special case. Try using a subclass--I don't know if it will work to show a field of type T, but it works in other cases (where no objects of type T are shown in the inspector, but the type is still a generic type). I'm not sure if it will work, though. In other words, don't try to directly show a generic type in the inspector (except List<T>).